# Using law of iterated expectations

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, expected-value, variance

[image]

. I think have the Poisson and uniform distributed equation which would be $e^{-10} (10^n/n!)$ and $1/50$ but I'm not sure how to apply the law and help would be appreciated.

Comment: Assuming $n$ customers arrived, that is $N=n$, can you compute the expected money spent?

Comment: Are you aware that answers can be marked as accepted $\left(\color{\limegreen}{\checkmark}\right)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $Y=\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$, hence $$E\{Y\}
{=
E\left\{\sum_{i=1}^NX_i\right\}
\\=
E_N\left\{E\left\{\sum_{i=1}^NX_i\Bigg|N\right\}\right\}
\\=
\sum_{n=50}^{100}\Pr\{N=n\}E\left\{\sum_{i=1}^NX_i\Bigg|N=n\right\}
\\=
\sum_{n=50}^{100}{1\over 51}\cdot E\left\{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\Bigg|N=n\right\}
\\=
{1\over 51}\cdot\sum_{n=50}^{100} E\left\{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\Bigg|N=n\right\}
\\=
{1\over 51}\cdot\sum_{n=50}^{100} 10n
\\=750\$
}
$$
where we have used the fact that the summation of two Poisson r.v.'s  with parameters $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ is a Poisson r.v.  with parameter $\lambda_1+\lambda_2$.

The variance is similarly calculated as
$$
E\{Y^2\}
{=
{1\over 51}\cdot\sum_{n=50}^{100} E\left\{\left[\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right]^2\Bigg|N=n\right\}
\\=
{1\over 51}\cdot\sum_{n=50}^{100} E\left\{\sum_{i,j}X_iX_j\Bigg|N=n\right\}
\\=
{1\over 51}\cdot\sum_{n=50}^{100} E\left\{\sum_{i=j}X_iX_j\Bigg|N=n\right\}
\\+
{1\over 51}\cdot\sum_{n=50}^{100} E\left\{\sum_{i\ne j}X_iX_j\Bigg|N=n\right\}
\\=
{1\over 51}\cdot\sum_{n=50}^{100} E\left\{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2\Bigg|N=n\right\}
\\+
{1\over 51}\cdot\sum_{n=50}^{100} \sum_{i\ne j}E\left\{X_iX_j\Bigg|N=n\right\}
\\=
{1\over 51}\cdot\sum_{n=50}^{100} 10n
\\+
{1\over 51}\cdot\sum_{n=50}^{100} \sum_{i\ne j}E\left\{X_i\Bigg|N=n\right\}
E\left\{X_j\Bigg|N=n\right\}
\\=
{1\over 51}\cdot\sum_{n=50}^{100} 10n
\\+
{1\over 51}\cdot\sum_{n=50}^{100} \sum_{i\ne j}100
\\=
E\{Y\}+
{1\over 51}\cdot\sum_{n=50}^{100} 100(n^2-n)
\\=577416{2\over 3}\$^2
}
$$
hence $${\sigma_Y^2=14916{2\over 3}\$^2\\\sigma_Y\approx 122.13\$}$$

Comment: I would have thought the expected sales was more likely to be $10\times \frac{50+100}{2}=750$

Comment: I understand everything up to how you managed to get the expectation for (Y|N) and forward

Comment: First of all, pardon me for a mistake. The answer should be around 740 which is slightly less than 750, but up to which line of the answer are you agree with me?

Comment: it's ok,  I am just confused where the 10n comes from?

Comment: This is because $E\{X_i\}=10$ and we have summed up $n$ numbers of them given $N=n$.

Comment: I am trying to solve the variance and I think we have to use Var(Y)=E(Y|^2N)-E(Y|N)^2

Comment: Also $E\{Y^2\}$ and $E\{Y^2|N=n\}$ can be calculated in a similar manner.

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes. The correct answer for average is $750\$ $ and more details on variance are added.